# Get query selector from within jQuery.fn method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have a function:

```
$.fn.foo = function (arg) {
    // some code
}
```

Called normally, like so:

```
$('#bar.baz').foo("banana");
```

Is it possible to retrieve the 'query' selector (`'#bar.baz'`) from within the function `$.fn.foo`?

For example:

```
$.fn.foo = function (arg) {
    console.log($(this).getQuerySelector()); // --> '#bar.baz'
}
```

Or is it necessary to pass it as a parameter (`$('#bar.baz').foo('#bar.baz', 'banana');`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical answer was to use the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property of the jQuery object:

```
$.fn.foo = function(arg) {
    console.log(this.selector);
};
```

However, that property is deprecated since jQuery 1.7:

> The `.selector` property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and is only
>   maintained to the extent needed for supporting `.live()` in the jQuery
>   Migrate plugin. It may be removed without notice in a future version.
>   The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could
>   be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the
>   jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods
>   may have changed the set.

Therefore, it is better to pass the selector as an explicit argument in newer code.

Comment: I knew the answer would be trivial, just couldn't seem to find it in the docs. Know the reason why it's deprecated? I'm using jQuery 2 and attempting to write a function that does what `.live()` did, as `on()` doesn't work with dynamic content.

Comment: @Der, it was deprecated because only `live()` was using it, and `live()` itself was deprecated and is now removed. In addition, that property never was reliable in the first place because the original selector and the content of the jQuery object can differ, as explained in the quote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is using .selector

```
console.log($(this).selector);
```